# Bash script remote variable to local script

Tags: bash, variables, ssh

I'm trying to make a script that uses variables from a remote script. Currently the script executes the remote script with an ssh user@server "/route/to/script.sh" command in the script. In that script I'm saving some variables. I wish to use these variables in my local script where I've began everything.

Any ideas how to do this?

Regards:
Bert

Comment: The remote script needs to print the variable values, then the local script has to read the output and assign to its variables.

Comment: Can you show me the how-to, please?

Comment: Cheers Mate! Will go for it then.

Comment: One important thing to cover here -- how much do you trust the remote machine? Many of the approaches (particularly if you want to transfer *multiple* variables, and let the remote system choose their names) have substantial security caveats. It's safer to just treat your data as data, and not try to let the remote system control local variables as such.

Comment: Don't confuse data with variables. A variable is a name that refers to data; you want the *data* from the remote script, not the variable.

Comment: The remote server will be literally on top of the local server and they will be connected directly with a LAN cable, so I can trust it 120% :)

Comment: chepner: No, I want a variable. A result would be saved into a variable, and I want to use the exact same variable locally. But I've solved it ust how Alfe suggested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of options possible.  One could be:

```
a=$(ssh user@server "/route/to/script.sh")
```

While the remote `script.sh` looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname
```

This way, the output of the command `hostname` (should be the name of the remote host) will end up in the local variable `a`.

Comment: I've done just the same. :) Thanks dude. upvoted it, but I haven't got enough rep, to mark it as an answer. Please do so yourself.